# Is there any problem using virtual members while joining two entities in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm querying some data by joining multiple tables in Linq.

Is there any problem using the virtual members for joining multiple tables?

here Table1, Table2, Table3 and Table4 are Entities
and Table1 has Table3 as virtual member, Table2 has Table4 as virtual member

```
from tbl1 in db.Table1
join tbl2 in db.Table2
on tbl1.Table3.property equals tbl2.Table4.property
where tbl1.Id == id && tbl2.SomeId == someId
select tbl2
```

I can able to fetch data, but wanted to know if there is **anything wrong** with this approach esp with following line of code?

**"on tbl1.Table3.property equals tbl2.Table4.property"**

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: No.  Usually the where is faster than a join.  Using a join is often used and does have advantages if you are returning a lot of data.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why do you think that this could be a problem?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin As I'm not using direct properties in "on" but virtual properties

Comment: @mjwills Yes it worked